# Relative Layout squishing child views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-imagebutton

I have an ImageView and TextView inside a RelativeLayout to move them all around as a group that sticks together. It looks fine in the Graphical Layout inside Eclipse.

(The blue shows the outline for the RelativeLayout):

[image]

However when I run the app, the child views appear squished toghether or on top of each other. The ImageView doesn't even show anymore. I'm not sure why this occurs?

[image]

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/squashcourt"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/squashcourt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_aboveB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Robin"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_B"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_aboveB"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/b_left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using a Samsung S4. Can anyone suggest something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of a RelativeLAyout containing a TextView and an ImageView, you could simplify all by using a single TextView which contains a compound drawable (`android:drawableBottom = "@drawable/b_left"`)

Comment: You can simply use a textView with drawableBottom. And the way you are using RelativeLayout is completely wrong dude, no use of orientation in Relativelayout. And the problem which comes in your code is because you are using your Relative layout as wrap_content, use it as match_parent. It will solved your poblem

Comment: bottom_drawable works perfect thanx, but if I used match_parent the layout would have stretched way bigger than I intend for it, so dunno where you got that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use simply `TextView` with bottom drawable .

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_aboveB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Robin"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Now you can move the `TextView` any where on the screen.